ERROR processing skip func while deploying contract
`
Im currently watching fcc solidity course and im trying to deploy a smart contract but it throws this error idk no what to do
ERROR processing skip func of /root/hardhat-fund-me-real/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
your text`Error: Cannot find module '../helper-hardhat-config
//00-deploy-mock.js
`const {network} = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChain, DECIMAL, INITIAL_ANSWER,} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
const { deploy, log } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
const chainId = network.config.chainId

if(developmentChain.includes(network.name)){
log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks......")
await deploy ("MockV3Aggregator", {
contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
from: deployer,
log: true,
args: [DECIMAL, INITIAL_ANSWER],

})
log("Mocks Deployed!!")
log("__________________________________________________________")
}
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]`

This is the packagejson file of my code
{ "name": "hardhat-fund-me-real", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "", "main": "index.js", "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }, "keywords": [], "author": "", "license": "ISC", "devDependencies": { "@chainlink/contracts": "^1.0.0", "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0", "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3", "ethers": "^5.7.2", "hardhat": "^2.22.2", "hardhat-deploy": "^0.12.2", "hardhat-deploy-ethers": "^0.4.1" }, "dependencies": { "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.6", "solc": "^0.8.8" } }
I am struggling with this problem almost tried everything but teh error isn't going 

